# Why dont parent classes are not automatically destruct in php?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to dig some PHP OOP features.
Here is my sample codes

```
<?php

abstract class Animal{
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        echo 'animal instruct'  . "\n";
    }
    public function eat(){
        return $this->name . ' is eating food.'  . "\n";
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo "animal destruct"  . "\n";
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    public function bark(){
        return $this->name . ' is barking.'  . "\n";
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo "dog destruct"  . "\n";
        parent::__destruct();
        
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal{
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    public function meow(){
        return $this->name . ' is meowing.'  . "\n";
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        parent::__destruct();
        echo "cat destruct" . "\n";
    }
}

$bobby = new Dog('Bobby');
echo $bobby->bark();
echo $bobby->eat();

$cat = new Cat("cat");
echo $cat->meow();
echo $cat->eat();
?>
```

When I run the code , the output is as follow

```
animal instruct
Bobby is barking.
Bobby is eating food.
animal instruct
cat is meowing.
cat is eating food.
animal destruct
cat destruct
dog destruct
animal destruct
```

When I remove this code from child classes

> parent::__destruct();

the parent class is not automatically destruct itself.

What I want to know is Do we need to destruct parent class in every child classes for some free memory space or PHP will do it itself?

Comment: You could ask the same for construction, too. That said, I have never had to create a destructor in PHP, I believe.

Comment: If the child class does not have a destructor, then the parent class destructor will be called. If the child class does have a destructor, then it overrides the parent unless the parent is specifically called. The same goes for the constructor.

Comment: This is not exclusive to destructors; *all* overridden methods must call their parent's implementation if they want the parent's implementation to run. You explicitly control whether you want the parent's implementation to run or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to unpick here:

- Once an object in PHP has no more references to it, the memory it uses will be freed. If it has the last reference to some other object, that object will also be freed, and so on. This is automatic, and largely invisible; you don't need to write any code in your class to make it happen, nor can you stop it happening, other than by keeping a reference to the object somewhere. (If there are circular references, they may not be freed immediately, but PHP will periodically check and free those as well.)
- **When** the object is freed, PHP will run a method called `__destruct`, if it exists. This method isn't *responsible* for freeing the object, it's just happening *as an effect* of PHP deciding to do so. It gives you a chance to do *extra* cleanup or checks *as well as* what PHP does automatically.
- When you inherit from a class, that inheritance is part of the *definition* of the object; creating an instance of the sub-class doesn't actually create two objects. So in your example, `$bobby` is an instance of `Dog`, and the memory that needs to be freed is the memory taken by that instance; there is no extra instance of `Animal` "inside" it.
- When you define *any* method in both a parent class and a sub-class, the definition in the sub-class *hides* the one in the parent class. If you add a definition of `eat()` in class `Dog`, it will be called *instead of* the definition in `Animal`. The same is true with "magic" methods like `__destruct`: when `$bobby` is freed, the engine will call `$bobby->__destruct()`, and find the definition in class `Dog` *instead of* the one in class `Animal`. By calling `parent::__destruct()` *inside* the definition of `Dog`, you are explicitly asking to run the "hidden" definition.

So the answer to your final question:

> Do we need to destruct parent class in every child classes for some free memory space or PHP will do it itself?

Is **No**. PHP will free the memory space *of the object* regardless of how you define the object; and there is no separate "parent memory" to free. It will *additionally* run the `__destruct` method on that object if one exists; that method will be resolved using the normal rules: look on sub-class first, else parent, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

So it says, the parent destructor won't be called automatically, as same is for the parent constructor.

If your parent class needs to do deconstruct work, you have to call it expliticly.

### Short answer

The destructor will only be called on instances.